# Python-Selenium getting emails from webpage

Tags: python, selenium

I am looking to extract the Name, Phone Numbers and Email addresses from [this](https://www.freedom55financial.com/ff/advisor/Ontario/Mississauga) page.

The code works, but the issue is that some of these names have multiple links in their "cards", so when I do the extraction, it throws off the whole chronology of the links thrown... for example:

> Julio (July) Anopol,  ,  , Mobile: 416-678-2916, mailto:julio.luis.anopol@freedom55financial.com
>
> Henry D. Arauag, Office: 905-276-1177 , Ext. 594 , Mobile: 647-649-7955 , mailto:henry.arauag@freedom55financial.com
>
> Rick Auckbaraullee , Office: 905-276-1177 , Ext. 557 , Mobile: 416-577-2377 , mailto:rick.auckbaraullee@freedom55financial.com
>
> Frank Basile , Office: 905-276-1177 , Ext. 469 , Mobile: 416-797-9316 , mailto:frank.basile@freedom55financial.com
>
> Janis Bellman , Office: 905-276-1177 , Ext. 601 , Mobile: 416-258-0630 , https://www.linkedin.com/in/janisbellman
>
> Sean Beneteau , Office: 905-363-5800 , Ext. 123 ,  , https://www.facebook.com/MyBellman/
>
> Carmen Briguglio , Office: 905-824-5660 ,  ,  , https://twitter.com/BellmanJanis
>
> Qi Jun (Steve) Cai , Office: 905-276-1177 , Ext. 591 , Mobile: 416-949-1069 , mailto:janis.bellman@freedom55financial.com

As you can see the sequence is thrown off, if the name has another links attached to their "card"

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# example option: add 'incognito' command line arg to options
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")

# create new instance of chrome in incognito mode
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Library/Application    Support/Google/chromedriver', chrome_options=option)

# go to website
browser.get("https://www.freedom55financial.com/ff/advisor/Ontario/Mississauga")

browser.implicitly_wait(4)

# extract names from parent element
all_names = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="advisor-results"]/article[*]/section/h2')

# extract all phone numbers
all_off_phones_numbers = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="advisor-results"]/article[*]/section/p[4]/a')

#extract all exts
all_exts = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="advisor-results"]/article[*]/section/p[5]')

#extract all cell numbers
all_cell_numbers = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="advisor-results"]/article[*]/section/p[6]/a')

#extract all email addys
all_emails = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="advisor-results"]/article[*]/footer/a[*]')

# print out all info
num_page_items = len(all_names)
for i in range(num_page_items):
    print(all_names[i].text + " , " + all_off_phones_numbers[i].text + " , " + all_exts[i].text + " , " + all_cell_numbers[i].text + " , " + all_emails[i].get_attribute('href'))
    # print(all_names[i].text + " , " + all_off_phones_numbers[i].text + " , " + all_exts[i].text + " , " + all_cell_numbers[i].text + " , " + all_emails[i].text)

browser.close()
```

One example of HTML CODE from the page showing how the information is contained:

```
<section id="advisor-results" class="advisor-results" role="region" aria-live="polite" >

<article class="advisor-results__advisor-card f55f English Portugese CIM Male Photo_Yes" aria-describedby="
f55-security-advisor-legend

">
<div class="advisor-image">
<img src="
/dsms/wcm/connect/ff/0a7d8558-3a70-4c24-8d10-
ff779a87d2e2/Amaral_Marcos_2016.jpg?MOD=AJPERES&amp;CACHEID=0a7d8558-3a70-4c24-8d10-ff779a87d2e2

" alt="" />                 </div>
<section class="advisor-details">

<h2>Marcus (Marcos) Amaral</h2>
<p class="advisor-credentials">CIM</p>
<p class="advisor-firm">


Freedom&nbsp;55 Financial


</p>
<p class="advisor-offerings"></p>

<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=1 City Centre Dr., Mississauga, ON, , L5B 1M2" data-card='map' target="_blank">
<address role="presentation">
<span class="address-line">1 City Centre Dr.</span>
<span class="address-line">Suite 1600</span>
<span class="address-line">Mississauga, ON</span>
<span class="address-line">L5B 1M2</span>
</address>
</a>
<p><a href="tel:905-276-1177" data-card="phone" >Office: 905-276-1177</a></p>
<p>Ext. 485</p>
<p><a href="tel:519-819-3241" data-card="phone" >Mobile: 519-819-3241</a></p>
</section>
<footer>


<a title='' data-card='email' target='' 
href='mailto:marcos.amaral@freedom55financial.com' ><i class='fa fa-
envelope-o' aria-label='Contact this advisor by email'></i></a>
</footer>
]</article>
```

I have tried various variations, looking by css selector, xpath contains text, etc, to no avail.

How can I make this work to get email?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the relevant HTML code. We do not want to investigate the page by looking at the link.

Comment: Factually, there is no such item as `Phone Numbers` on the Webpage. Either it's a `Mobile` or `Office` + `Ext`

Comment: @JeroenHeier Added.

Comment: @DebanjanB the phone numbers are not giving me too much issue, its getting the emails. The phone names, addresses and phone numbers are all under one element. Whereas the emails are essentially in the parent element. I cant seem to figure out how to make this work.